# Assign HTML.Textbox length base on use input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have Html.DropdownList control, base on the dropdown selection I need to set the length of the text box.

Ex:
I have different registration number information in drop down

> StudentRegestrationID
>
> StaffRegistrationID
>
> GustID

When even ever I select `StudentRegestrationID` its set the (Html.Textbox) control `maxLength` to 8, else for other two I need to set max length as 5.

Here `maxlength` of the control must be decide by the dropdown selection value.

I need to implement it JQuery any code help are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $('input').attr('maxlength',$(this).val());
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/y1aza1t5/2/)